# jQuery use of vertical scrollbar and mousedown - FireFox works, IE has issue

Tags: jquery, css, scrollbar, overflow, onmousedown

I have a menu scripted with jQuery, which pops out when triggered by an event. It has a vertical scroll bar on the side. The scrolling works fine in FireFox, but not in IE (8 or 9). I guess it has something to do with the `mousedown` event, which is needed to select an item from the menu.

```
    .mousedown(function (event) {
        var li = get_element_from_event(event, "li");
        if(li){
            return false;
        }
```

In case of IE, when clicking with the mouse on the scrollbar, the menu collapses again (as if the user made a selection).

Is this a common problem in IE (i.e. issues with the scrollbar)?

I think it also has to do with the following snippet of scrollbar code

```
$(".token-input-list")[0].scrollTop = $(".token-input-list")[0].scrollHeight;
```

Comment: Have you tried using .click instead of .mousedown?

Comment: Didn't help. I'm not sure though whether I'm looking at this problem the right way. Wouldn't changing the following snippet, which handles the scroll bar, be the solution?   $(".token-input-list")[0].scrollTop = $(".token-input-list")[0].scrollHeight;

Comment: Hmm... It might be something more related to a css portion of the menu... overflow: auto is causing errors like this in IE. Anyone knows of a solution or workaround.

Comment: Please show more of your code, especially your HTML, and also indicate which element you are attaching the .mousedown event to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your input - I found quite a bit of buggyness on the scrollbar issue, so I solved it by inlcuding a nice list script found here: http://rascarlito.free.fr/hoverscroll/. Dit the trick for IE, and thus for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what `get_element_from_event()` does, and what else you're doing with `mousedown`, IE may be behaving correctly--if the event target is not an element, it will supposedly return false for `li`, and so it will fail `if(li)` and therefore not return false for `mousedown`, but keep on chugging along.

As far as fixing it goes, you'll want to find out what IE is returning for `li` (via an alert or the console) and either test for it in `get_element_from_event()` or in a new var/function.

Comment: Thanks for your input - I found quite a bit of buggyness on the scrollbar issue, so I solved it by inlcuding a nice list script found here: http://rascarlito.free.fr/hoverscroll/. Dit the trick for IE, and thus for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your .mousedown event is attached to the same element the scrollbar is on, move your .mousedown event to a new div *inside* the div that has the scrollbar.

Comment: Thanks for your input - I found quite a bit of buggyness on the scrollbar issue, so I solved it by inlcuding a nice list script found here: http://rascarlito.free.fr/hoverscroll/. Dit the trick for IE, and thus for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that using the global window.event object, and not jQuery's event object. window.event only works in some browsers, and it is not a W3C standard.

jQuery normalizes the event object so it's the same in all browsers. The event handler is passed that jQuery event object as a parameter.  using that.

```
$(".class_name").mousedown(function (e) {

  switch (e.which) {
    case 1: //leftclick
        //...
        break;
    case 3: //rightclick
        //...
        break;
  }
});
```